# how to send Content-Length in rest assure ,Since encountering error that "Content-Length header already present"

Tags: api, post, automation, rest-assured

I am performing post operation using RestAssure and where in header I am passing Content-Length as below -
**queryParam().header("Content-Length", "value_Of_It")**

and due to that, I am encountering the error that "**Content-Length header already present"**.
it would be great if someone can  help me out to resolve it ?

Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present

And below are the headers gets added in postman by default,So while automating in Rest Assure d i need t pass them if not then how to resolve since getting 400 Bad request ? -

[image]

Comment: can any one answer ?

Comment: I'm curious, Why do you need to send "Content-length"?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17  While sending request from Postman its automatically added .So passing it..So while adding in rest assure I am getting the error and if I am removing or commenting it out I am getting 400 Bad request error ,Could you please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Rest-Assured automatically add `Content-Length` to header when doing the POST request. I've already tested with Postman proxy to see all information in Rest-Assured request.

Code:

```
given().proxy(5555)
       .body("test")
       .post("http://postman-echo.com/post");
```

[image]

If I add another `Content-Length`, I will get the same error as yours.